# In Gradle, how programmatically to exclude then force a dependency?

Tags: gradle

The end goal is to replace versions of transitive dependencies with a different version. The caveat is that the replacement should be picked up by those dependent upon the library being built (I don't know if it's a standard Gradle or a plugin but if we `exclude` a transitive dependency, the produced `ivy.xml` file will have that information).

One possible way to achieve the end goal is to `exclude` the dependency in question then force that dependency later on.

The way to `exclude` a dependency is with something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org:name:version' {
        exclude(group: 'group', module: 'module')
    }
}
```

The way to `force` a dependency is with something like:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails dependencyResolveDetails ->
            final requestedDependency = dependencyResolveDetails.requested
            if (requestedDependency.group == 'org' && requestedDependency.name == 'name') {
                force 'group:module:good_version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to tie the two together, the `resolutionStrategy` must know which dependencies actually `exclude`d the transitive dependency that will later be `force`d. How can this be done in a generic way (assuming there's a generic way to do the `exclude`)? If there isn't a way to tie the two together, is there a different way to achieve the end goal?

Comment: compile ('com.lib:library:X.Y.Z) { exclude group: 'other-library:project' }\n compile 'other-library:project:X.Y.Z'

Comment: If your library is transitive inside a project and you need to bring it to the parent project, i.e. a logger library, use provided instead of compiled. That brings a virtual version of the library that needs later compiled by the parent project.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM, I want to do it programmatically since it's a multi-module project and I want to keep things DRY.

Comment: There's a fine line between genius and madness and it isn't me who draws it. Your solution looks awesome tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, abstract the dependencies so they look something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile dep('org:name')
}
```

The `dep` function can then be defined in a way which will take care of the automatic exclusions:

```
final rev = [
    'group:module': 'good_version'
    'org:name': 'version']

ext.rev = { m ->
    rev[m]
}

final dep = { m ->
    "${m}:${ext.rev(m)}"
}

final forcedTransitiveDeps = [
        'org:name': [
            dep('group:module')]].withDefault({[]})

ext.forcedTransitiveDeps = { m ->
    forcedTransitiveDeps[m]
}

ext.dep = { m ->
    if (!forcedTransitiveDeps.containsKey(m)) {
        project.dependencies.create(dep(m))
    } else {
        project.configure(
                project.dependencies.create(dep(m)),
                {
                    forcedTransitiveDeps[m].each { dependency ->
                        final dependencyParts = dependency.split(':')
                        exclude(group: dependencyParts[0], module: dependencyParts[1])
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

Finally, to re-introduce and force the dependencies:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    subproject.afterEvaluate {
        subproject.configurations.all { Configuration configuration ->
            final dependencies = configuration.getDependencies()
            final forcedDependencies = (dependencies.collect { dependency ->
                forcedTransitiveDeps("${dependency.group}:${dependency.name}")
            }).flatten()
            if (!forcedDependencies.isEmpty()) {
                logger.info("Forcing ${subproject} dependencies on ${forcedDependencies} as per `ext.forcedTransitiveDeps`.")
                dependencies.addAll(forcedDependencies.collect { forcedDependency ->
                    subproject.dependencies.create(forcedDependency)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```